# I have been trying this code from 3 days now. The code is for a Wikipedia search

Tags: python, wikipedia

```
#Run the code and type the topic you want to be searched.
import wikipedia
import random
print("Type the topic you want to be searched.")
print("If an error occurrs, I am sorry but I got no Error Handler in here.")
print("Which means you jus hafta re-run the code.")
while True:
    try:
        print("Enter a topic to be searched for in wikipedia:-")
        x = input()
        results = wikipedia.summary(x, sentences=2)
        page = wikipedia.page(x)
        print(results)
        print(f"Link for the page of this information:- {page.url}")
        print("=============================+=============================+=============================+=============================+=============================+")
    except wikipedia.DisambiguationError as e:
        redirectedpage = random.choice(e.options)
        result = wikipedia.summary(redirectedpage, sentences=2)
        errorpage = wikipedia.page(redirectedpage)
        print(result)
        print(errorpage.url)
        print("=============================+=============================+=============================+=============================+=============================+")
        continue
```

But i get an error....not exactly an error but a suggestion and i cant make out what exactly it is

> Warning (from warnings module):
> File "C:\Users\Me\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\wikipedia\wikipedia.py", line 389
> lis = BeautifulSoup(html).find_all('li')
> GuessedAtParserWarning: No parser was explicitly specified, so I'm using the best available HTML parser for this system ("html.parser"). This usually isn't a problem, but if you run this code on another system, or in a different virtual environment, it may use a different parser and behave differently.
> The code that caused this warning is on line 389 of the file C:\Users\Me\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\wikipedia\wikipedia.py. To get rid of this warning, pass the additional argument 'features="html.parser"' to the BeautifulSoup constructor.

Can you please help?

Comment: Here is a discussion of the issue and the known solution. https://github.com/goldsmith/Wikipedia/issues/107

Comment: Thank you. This did help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The wikipedia package you're using is internally fetching wikipedia's page as html and parsing it using BeautifulSoup to get the desired output.

The problem is that the author of this library has not specifically mentioned the type of file that needs to be parsed, which is html in this case.

This is not an issue because BeautifulSoup is automatically picking up html but yes, on different systems results might differ(although unlikely).

The only way to fix this is either ask the author to fix the library or stop using this library and fetch the page yourself using requests and BeautifulSoup.

Comment: I did try that forgetting that I am a beginner myself and ended up confusing more. But thank you

Comment: I went through the github repository of this package. Lools like it is not maintained anymore. So tough luck trying to fix this error from the library